# What statistical test should I use for this analysis where I want to compare the similarity of two histograms and return a single value percentage?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, dataset, histogram, model-comparison, similarities

I need some help with what statistical test I should use for my data analysis. I have a Data set A, which is an array of 5000 numbers, ALL of which are zero, and a Data set B, which is an array of random continuous numbers that do not necessarily follow a normal distribution. Both data sets are plotted on a histogram for visual aid. Data set A is my "ideal" and Data set B is my "measured" - I would like to compare the similarity of Data set B to Data set A (it would output a single figure such as a percentage similarity). I would then go on to test another Data set C (the same style of array as data set B - as in it does not have normal distribution and is continuous numbers) and compare its similarity % with Data set A. I would then be able to make a "ranking" on whether Data set B or Data set C was most similar to Data set A. Basically answering the question of "what data set is most similar to the ideal straight vertical line at zero?"

Some of the considerations:

- The similarity value has to account for the shape (ie. the histogram of Data set B will rank with a higher similarity percentage the closer it is to a vertical straight line as in the ideal data set A)
- The similarity value has to account for x axis distance on the
  histogram (ie. the further from zero the poorer the % similarity to
  data set A)
- The weighting of each has to be equal (ie. neither the
  shape or distance on the x axis is more important)
- Because the
  weighting is equal, if data set B was a straight line at -5, it
  should have the same % similarity to data set A if it had been a
  straight line at +5.
- the order of the values in array B does not
  matter as they are plotted on the histogram

I'm essentially trying to rank data sets against the "ideal" data set A (but taking into account non normal distribution, histogram shape similarity, distance etc). I have no idea what test to apply that can give me a % similarity to the ideal under these conditions.

Thank you so so so much.

Comment: It is difficult to say for sure without seeing your histograms. Possibilities: With appropriate binning of histograms you might make a contingency table with bins vs. (A, B, C) to see that A, B, C are not have homogenous distribution. You also might make comparisons of A vs B, A vs C, B vs C with two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests. // If A is really degenerate at 0, it seems it is obviously different from B and C, so maybe those comparisons don't need formal tests.

Comment: @BruceET thank you for replying. I see what you mean. My data set of A is the perfect/ideal histogram is just a straight vertical line at zero, whereas my data set B and C are histograms that have a similar spike at zero but with small side lobes and outliers. Im trying to find a way to quantify whether A or B is more similar with an actual output value (e.g. something like - the closer the output value is to zero the more similar that histogram is to A). - hopefully this helps visualise the histograms and data a bit better